# FFMPEG fit 1920x1080 video in 1080x1920 video (Instagram Reels)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to post a video on Instagram. My current video is 1920x1080, but for Instagram reels it needs to be in 1080x1920 resolution (Basically Vertical). But instead of posting the video on its side, I like to post it with black bars (see image below). But I don't know which transform commands I need to use in ffmpeg to make this work (and also couldn't find any relevant posts).

[image: Porsche Style 1080p video in Vertical video]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fit into a 1080x1920 canvas, use the scale and pad filters.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:-1:-1,setsar=1" -c:a copy output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this post for future reference. I ended up using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: This pads the input vertically so you will go from 1920x1080 to 1920x3412,